# Can frequent ultrasound diagnostics be harmful?

Tags: human-biology, ultrasound

Are there any short or long term effects apparent in tissues if a zone (or the whole) of human body is scanned with ultrasonic waves often?

Comment: Medical advice questions are off-topic here, I think if you edit the last portion out and make the first question more general to the science behind it, it will be okay.

Comment: You might want to see [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/ultrasound-during-pregnancy) though

Comment: @RoryM Thanks for editing and reopening my question. Your hat covers your eyes btw °<|)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultrasound is considered a safe procedure ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2678243)) which is accepted by the WHO as well ([reference](http://whqlibdoc.who.int/trs/WHO_TRS_875.pdf)). There have been studies however, that show the link of ultrasound treatment to some undesirable traits.

Ultrasound could be possibly linked to a decrease in body weight on birth of infants ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8105165)).

Frequent use of ultrasound may influence babies scanned to grow up left handed ([reference](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/uog.9055/abstract))

A significant migration of neurons (change of neurons from their rightful area) has been observed in mice on exposing them to ultrasound at the prenatal stage. ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1538990/)).

A study has found detrimental affects to the brains of mice on exposure to ultrasound in the fetal stage ([reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12034351)).

So based on these papers, I wouldn't call them a 100% safe but these tests all relate to repeated usage of ultrasound imaging. Ultrasound usage sparingly and on valid medical indication should not be a matter of concern.